# wordpress, apache redirection question

Tags: apache, wordpress

I have a wordpress application thats currently the only application on the domain. 
Now in this application, I've just created a /presentations folder...

How can I present anything stored in just this /presentations folder from getting redirected...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress's `.htaccess` file only redirects if a file matching the request URI can't be found. Files in your `/presentations` folder should be unaffected.

If you're redirecting in some other way than the default WordPress `.htaccess` rules, we'll need to see the config for that.

Comment: Not sure how its redirecting but I solved the problem by renaming file to .htm, instead of html.... clearly there is a rule there to redirect all html files

Comment: There's not (check if you don't believe!), but I'm glad the situation is resolved.